# keras distributed model and data

Tags: python, openmp, keras, theano

Let suppose I have a keras model and a function `train_model(data)` to train it on some data.

I would like to know if it is possible to combine/merge identical architecture, identical hyperparam models that have been trained separately/independently?

```
python train_model( data1 ) ### one one epoch
python train_model( data2 ) ### one one epoch
...
```

then

```
load( model1 )
load( model2 )
model3 = combine( model1, model2 )
### model3 equivalent to 2 epochs of learning.
```

I try to understand/find a way to distribute the learning.

Comment: You should build two networks(exactly same) that has been trained, then load the weights for each of them separately. Then you can combine the outputs using Merge layer. Remember you should use `Model` API

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried this?

```
from keras.models import load_model

# load models - it is just the architecture
model1 = load_model('path/to/trained/model1.h5')
model2 = load_model('path/to/trained/model2.h5')

# load trained weights
model1.load_weights('path/to/weights/from/model1.hdf5')
model2.load_weights('path/to/weights/from/model2.hdf5')

# create a model that will merge both 1 and 2
model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([model1, model2], mode = 'concat'))
model.add(Dense(1)) # for regression, use you last Dense layer here
model.compile(#your compiling parameters)

# use your merged model
model.predict(dataset_to_be_predicted)
```

The idea is from [here](https://statcompute.wordpress.com/2017/01/08/an-example-of-merge-layer-in-keras/)

Comment: Your answer will concatenate the two loaded model to form one new architecture (two branches merging in the end ) (btw Merge give a deprecated warning for me). But it is not exactly what I want. I would like to combine model 1 and 2 to form a model 3 that have the same architecture as model 1 and 2! In a way that it 'average' (or something else) the weights. Model3 will be mixing the two learning of the two model.

Comment: I am not sure that you can do that so easy. The weights are saved according to the architecture, meaning that two different architectures have different amout of weights. Merging them would mean taking the mean or something similar, but if there is a different amount, it would not know what to merge. Have you considered predicting with both models and averaging the result? If it is a classification, you could take the class that got a higher probability.

Comment: the architecture is fixed, so no problem there. I just want to know if it is possible to learn to epoch separately/independently and then combine the weights in a way in order to obtain a model as if it has been trained by two epochs.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'trained by two epochs'. An epoch is an entire pass through a dataset. If you have two models with the same fixed architecture, the only possible different things are the hyperparameters. You could dig deeper into tensorflow and take the mean of the weights yourself, I just do not see the use for that. Would you mind editing your question to provide more information on what you want to do?

Comment: I want to distribute the learning, and then build the model fully learned.